# Redirect the standard error in the ${var:?} construct

Tags: bash, io-redirection

From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${parameter:?word}
> If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of word (or a message to that effect if word is not present) is **written to the standard error** and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

So why can't I redirect the error to `/dev/null` (or anywhere else):

```
$ ${a:?} 2> /dev/null
bash: a: parameter null or not set
```

Neither with `echo`:

```
$ echo ${a:?} 2> /dev/null
bash: a: parameter null or not set
$ echo Hello world ${a:?} 2> /dev/null
bash: a: parameter null or not set
```

*My bash version is 4.3.42*.

---

#### Update:

To not divert my question, I need to say `a` is not defined and it will never be, so my question doesn't apply when it is defined and for that I don't care if `a` expands to something that isn't a command, alias, etc...

Consider this example to not get confused:

```
$ echo ${a:=1} ${b:?} ${c:=3}
bash: b: parameter null or not set
$ echo "a: $a - c: $c"
a: 1 - c:
```

Comment: Just enclose it in curlies: `{ ${a:?}; } 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: @gniourf, that solves the problem, but why do I need to enclose it in crulies in order to work? I'm *grouping* just one command, I expected to work the same without the curlies. Any hint?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure _why_ you need grouping (that's why I only commented); the same happens with the `time` builtin. See it as a feature: consider the case `f() { echo >&2 "hello $1"; }`. Thanks to this behavior, in the call `f "${a:?}"`, you can determine easily which message goes where: `f "${a:?}" 2>/dev/null` v.s. `{ f "${a:?}" 2>&3; } 3>&2 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: From the bash `man` pages:  "*The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter
       and  variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution
       (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname  expansion.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the order in which the shell interprets commands.

This is specified by the [Posix standard, volume XSH, section 2.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01). (Various shells, including bash, have extensions to this process, but the basics don't change):

> 1. The shell reads its input from a file (see sh), from the -c option or from the system() and popen() functions defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008. If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.
> 2. The shell breaks the input into tokens: words and operators; see Token Recognition.
> 3. The shell parses the input into simple commands (see Simple Commands) and compound commands (see Compound Commands).
> 4. The shell performs various expansions (separately) on different parts of each command, resulting in a list of pathnames and fields to be treated as a command and arguments; see wordexp.
> 5. The shell performs redirection (see Redirection) and removes redirection operators and their operands from the parameter list.
> 6. The shell executes a function (see Function Definition Command), built-in (see Special Built-In Utilities), executable file, or script, giving the names of the arguments as positional parameters numbered 1 to n, and the name of the command (or in the case of a function within a script, the name of the script) as the positional parameter numbered 0 (see Command Search and Execution).
> 7. The shell optionally waits for the command to complete and collects the exit status (see Exit Status for Commands).

Here, the relevant parts are steps 4 through 6. By the time we get to step 4, the shell has identified the command which it is about to run. It then performs the various expansions indicated, including `${a:?}`. At this point, we have not yet started to execute the command, nor have we done any redirections.

In step 5, the redirections are executed and removed from the command line. (left to right).

In step 6, the command name is identified (since it might depend on an expansion from step 4), the name is identified as either a special built-in, an alias, or an external program -- in which case the executable is found -- and finally the command is actually run, in an environment in which the redirects performed in step 5 apply.

So redirecting stderr does not apply to parameter expansions. Any error message generated during parameter expansion is sent to the shell environment's current standard error.

The construct `{ command-list }` is a compound command. As indicated in [Posix XSH section 2.9.4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04): (highlight added):

> The shell has several programming constructs that are "compound commands", which provide control flow for commands. Each of these compound commands has a reserved word or control operator at the beginning, and a corresponding terminator reserved word or operator at the end. In addition, *each can be followed by redirections on the same line as the terminator. Each redirection shall apply to all the commands within the compound command that do not explicitly override that redirection.*

So redirections applied to the compound command apply for the duration of the compound command, and consequently include output *by the shell* during execution of the compound command.

It is worth noting that:

```
${a:=1} ${b:?} ${c:=3}
```

is not correct. If `$b` had a value -- say "B" --, so that execution of the command was not interrupted, then the command to be executed would be `1`, because the result of the expansion would be:

```
1 B 3
```

(assuming that `a` and `c` were assigned values by the default assignment construct). That would attempt to run the command `1`, giving it arguments `B` and `3`. Since this happens *after* redirects have been applied in step 5, the error message (`1: not found`) will be redirected, which means that you won't see it if you've redirected stderr to `/dev/null`.

If you want to perform one or more parameter settings using conditional expansions, you should use the `:` (no-op) command:

```
: ${a:=1} ${b:?} ${c:=3}
```

Finally, it is correct that an error during parameter expansion is likely to interrupt command execution. If the command line appeared in a script (so that the shell were not interactive), then failure of `${b:?}` causes "the shell exits with a non-zero exit status" (from [Posix XSH section 2.6.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), and also in the bash manual as quoted in the OP), which would void all the variable settings since they are local to the executing shell. XSH 2.6.2 goes on to say "An interactive shell need not exit", and indeed neither `bash` nor `dash` interactive shells exit. But the error is an error and it interrupts command execution. That this should be the case is suggested by [Posix XSH section 2.8.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01):

> If a command fails during word expansion or redirection, its exit status shall be greater than zero.

While that doesn't explicitly say that command execution is interrupted by an error, it seems a clear indication, since the command's exit status has already been set by the error. And certainly the shells I've tried do that.

Comment: Thanks for the references, they shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `bash` besides of printing to the standard error, it **discards current command** if the variable is not set.

Example (see `c` is not assigned):

```
$ ${a:=1} ${b:?} ${c:=3}
bash: b: parameter null or not set
$ echo "a: $a - c: $c"
a: 1 - c:
```

So why the error is not redirected?:

```
$ ${d:?} 2> /dev/null
bash: d: parameter null or not set
```

It's because `2> /dev/null` never executes because the parameter expansion happens fisrt and discards the rest of the command in this case.

---

#### My proof

We can see what's happenning in the `bash` source code.
Function call stack (snippets):

```c
static WORD_LIST *
shell_expand_word_list (tlist, eflags)
     WORD_LIST *tlist;
     int eflags;
{
    ...
  expanded = expand_word_internal // LOOK!
(tlist->word, 0, 0, &has_dollar_at, &expanded_something);

      if (expanded == &expand_word_error || expanded == &expand_word_fatal)
    {
      /* By convention, each time this error is returned,
         tlist->word->word has already been freed. */
      tlist->word->word = (char *)NULL;

      /* Dispose our copy of the original list. */
      dispose_words (orig_list);
      /* Dispose the new list we're building. */
      dispose_words (new_list);

      last_command_exit_value = EXECUTION_FAILURE;
      if (expanded == &expand_word_error)
        exp_jump_to_top_level (DISCARD); // LOOK!
      else
        exp_jump_to_top_level (FORCE_EOF);
    }
    ...
}

#define DISCARD     2   /* Discard current command. */
```

---

```c
static WORD_LIST *
expand_word_internal(word, quoted, isexp, contains_dollar_at, expanded_something)
     WORD_DESC *word;
     int quoted, isexp;
     int *contains_dollar_at;
     int *expanded_something;
{
    ...
    case '$':
      ...
      tword = param_expand (string, &sindex, quoted, expanded_something, // LOOK!
                   &temp_has_dollar_at, &quoted_dollar_at,
                   &had_quoted_null, pflags);
      has_dollar_at += temp_has_dollar_at;
      split_on_spaces += (tword->flags & W_SPLITSPACE);

      if (tword == &expand_wdesc_error || tword == &expand_wdesc_fatal)
        {
          free (string);
          free (istring);
          return ((tword == &expand_wdesc_error) ? &expand_word_error
                             : &expand_word_fatal);
        }
    ...
}
```

---

```c
/* Expand a single ${xxx} expansion.  The braces are optional.  When
   the braces are used, parameter_brace_expand() does the work,
   possibly calling param_expand recursively. */
static WORD_DESC *
param_expand (string, sindex, quoted, expanded_something,
          contains_dollar_at, quoted_dollar_at_p, had_quoted_null_p,
          pflags)
     char *string;
     int *sindex, quoted, *expanded_something, *contains_dollar_at;
     int *quoted_dollar_at_p, *had_quoted_null_p, pflags;
{
    ...
    case LBRACE:
      tdesc = parameter_brace_expand (string, &zindex, quoted, pflags, // LOOK!
                      quoted_dollar_at_p,
                      contains_dollar_at);

      if (tdesc == &expand_wdesc_error || tdesc == &expand_wdesc_fatal)
    return (tdesc);
    ...
}

 *`LBRACE` means what follows the dollar sign*
```

---

```c
/* ${[#][!]name[[:][^[^]][,[,]]#[#]%[%]-=?+[word][:e1[:e2]]]} */
static WORD_DESC *
parameter_brace_expand (string, indexp, quoted, pflags, quoted_dollar_atp,
    contains_dollar_at)
     char *string;
     int *indexp, quoted, *quoted_dollar_atp, *contains_dollar_at, pflags;
{
    ...
    else if (c == '?')
    {
      parameter_brace_expand_error (name, value); // LOOK!
      return (interactive_shell ? &expand_wdesc_error : &expand_wdesc_fatal);
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```c
/* Deal with the right hand side of a ${name:?value} expansion in the case
   that NAME is null or not set.  If VALUE is non-null it is expanded and
   used as the error message to print, otherwise a standard message is
   printed. */
static void
parameter_brace_expand_error (name, value)
     char *name, *value;
{
  WORD_LIST *l;
  char *temp;

  last_command_exit_value = EXECUTION_FAILURE;  /* ensure it's non-zero */
  if (value && *value)
    {
      l = expand_string (value, 0);
      temp =  string_list (l);
      report_error ("%s: %s", name, temp ? temp : "");  /* XXX was value not ""*/
      FREE (temp);
      dispose_words (l);
    }
  else
    report_error (_("%s: parameter null or not set"), name); // LOOK!

  /* Free the data we have allocated during this expansion, since we
     are about to longjmp out. */
  free (name);
  FREE (value);
}

report_error (format, arg1, arg2)
     char *format, *arg1, *arg2;
{
  fprintf (stderr, format, arg1, arg2);
  fprintf (stderr, "\n");
}
```